# PHP multiple-inheritance

Tags: php, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I try to inherit multiple classes from each other, but something wrong happens somewhere. The classes are the following:

Part of the MobilInterface class:

```
class MobileInterface
{

private $config;

private $errorData;

private $data;

private $output;

private $job;

public $dbLink;

public function __construct($config) {
    $this->config = $config;
}

public function initialize($job) {
    $this->dbLink = $this->createDbInstance($this->config);
    require_once 'jobs/' . strtolower($this->config->joblist[$job]) .'.php';
    $this->job = new $this->config->joblist[$job]($this);               
}

public function run($params) {
    $job = $this->job;
    $this->data = $this->job->run($_GET);

}
 }
```

Mobil Interface is the main interface, which calls the Kupon class based on a string in the $config. My problem is that i want more Kupon like classes and wanted to make a BaseJob class to be able to write each Job class without the constructor.

The problem is that the Kupon class can't see the $dbLink and the $config variables.

The BaseJob class:

```
 <?php
class BaseJob
{

public $interface;

public $dbLink;

public $config;

public function __construct(MobileInterface $interface) {
    $this->interface = $interface;
    $this->config = $this->interface->get('config');
    $this->dbLink = $this->interface->get('dbLink');
}

}
?>
```

And the Kupon class:

```
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct(MobileInterface $interface);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Is't it the purpose of interface to have the function signature and the classes implementing them should implement those functions ?

Comment: Having a **class** with *Interface* in the name is a giant, putrid code smell. Also, PHP doesn't support multiple inheritance (although I don't see an example of that in your question)

Comment: I just want to make a BaseJob class that makes all the variable assign for the Kupon class, I will have multiple Kupon classes, they are 'jobs'.

Comment: I've got it, 

    function __construct($interface){
  // var_dump($interface);
  parent::__construct($interface);
 }
I needed the $interface in the constructor params

Comment: If you've found the solution, please create an answer and accept it.